# Azure Functions anonymous authentication - retrieve the name of the user that triggered the Function

Tags: powershell, azure-functions

I have an anonymous Azure Function running on Powershell, and I would like to display in the script the name of the user that triggered the Function. In the Trigger Metadata I don't see such an information and since the function is Anonymous, the username is not part of the headers. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Euh no. That's the whole point of being anonymous. Unless you add it manually as a header or something on the calling side.